Alembic doesn't see SQLModel models and creates empty migrations
I'm using SQLModel with Alembic for database migrations in my project. However, Alembic doesn't seem to recognize my models and creates empty migrations.
Here's the code for my model:
from sqlmodel import Field, SQLModel
from app.model.base_model import BaseModel

class UserType(Enum):
    buyer = "buyer"
    seller = "seller"

class User(BaseModel):
    user_id: int = Field(default=None, primary_key=True, index=True)
    role: UserType = Field(default="buyer")
    name: str = Field(default=None)
    email: str = Field(default=None)
    description: str = Field(default=None)
    password_hash: str = Field(default=None)
    profile_picture: str = Field(default=None)

In my env.py file, I'm importing the models like this:
from app import model # noqa(import from init.py)
And I've set the target_metadata to SQLModel.metadata:
target_metadata = SQLModel.metadata
Despite this, when I run alembic revision --autogenerate, it creates an empty migration file with upgrade() and downgrade() functions that just contain pass.
I've followed the documentation closely, but I can't figure out why Alembic isn't recognizing my models. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

try importing module with your models explicitly. Does it help?

I tried it, but still same(

is BaseModel from base_model a subclass of SQLModel?

Yes, it is inherited

I had the same problem and I resolved it by manually modifying the env.py file. I modified it like this:
from dbModels import dbChat, dbImage, dbLike # ADDED
target_metadata = Base.metadata # ADDED


I solved this problem with adding table=True in model)
